# Overriding the allDay Slot programmatically

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am attempting to override the CSS for the all day slot in full Calendar programatically. Obviously I can override the current styling but I am attempting to change the all day slot's position to fixed after the user has scrolled to a certain point. This cannot be done with the className inputs as the allDayClassNames only overrides the section that displays the text "all day". Is there current functionality to override the entire slot programatically or is the only current option to override the CSS statically?

I have tried to use the slotClassNames input and the allDayClassnames but these do not give me access to the all day slot itself. I cannot make the all day slot sticky as it is embedded many times in css that is restrictive and must remain that way.

Comment: AFAIK there is no API option for this, you just have to modify the CSS yourself